# Cannot read property 'style' of null when try to call a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Good day, I am new on this. I am having an error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" on my second button I don't see what I have missed or what I am doing wrong because the first button is calling the model without any error when the second one is giving and error. can you please help below is my code

```html
<div class="w3-container" >
  <h2 align="center">Welcome To Funding Sessions</h2>
    <div align="center">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-green w3-large">Login</button>
    
    
<button onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-green w3-large">Register</button>
   </div> 
   
      <div class="w3-panel w3-green">
     
     
      <div class="w3-panel w3-red"></div>
      
     
    
  <div id="login" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

      <div class="w3-center"><br>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <h1>FS LOGIN</h1>
      </div>

      <form class="w3-container" method="POST" action="#">
        <div class="w3-section">
          <label><b>Username</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="usrname" required>
          <label><b>Password</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
          <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-left w3-red">Cancel</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('forgot').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-right w3-orange">Forgot Password</button>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="forgot" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

      <div class="w3-center"><br>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('forgot').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <h1>FS PASSWORD RECOVERY</h1>
      </div>

      <form class="w3-container" method="POST" action="#">
        <div class="w3-section">
          <label><b>Registered Email</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="user-email" id="user-email" required>
          <input type="submit" name="forgot" id="forgot-password" value="Reset password" class="w3-button w3-block w3-green" />
         
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('forgot').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">Cancel</button>
        <span class="w3-right w3-padding"><a href="#">Support Help?</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    
   
    <div id="reset" class="modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

      <div class="w3-center"><br>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('reset').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <h1>CREATE NEW PASSWORD</h1>
      </div>

      <form class="w3-container" method="POST" action="#">
        <div class="w3-section">
          <label><b>New Password</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="password" placeholder="Enter New password" name="member_password" required>
          
          <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" required>
          <input type ="hidden" name="token_id" value="<?php echo ($_GET["token_id"])?>" >
            <input type ="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo ($_GET["email"])?>" >
          <input type="submit" name="reset-password" id="reset-password" value="Reset Password" class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding">
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('reset').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">Cancel</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('forgot').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-right w3-orange">Support</button>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

      
      
    
   
  <div id="register" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

    <div class="w3-center"><br>
   <span onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
   <h1>FS REGISTER</h1>
    </div>
    
    <form class="w3-container" method="POST" action="#">
   <div class="w3-section">
     <label><b>Name</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="name" required>
    
    <label><b>Surname</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="surname" required>
    
    <label><b>Cell Number</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Cell Number" name="cell" required>
    
    <label><b>Email</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" required>
    
    
     <label><b>Password</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    
    <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpsw" required>
    
    
    
    
    <label><b>Referrer Email</b></label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" Style="color:red" type="text" name="referrer_id" placeholder="Ignore if no one invited you" value="#" >
    
     <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" name="signup" type="submit">Register</button>
   </div>
    </form>

    <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">Cancel</button>
   
    </div>
  </div>
   </div> 
    
  
    

</div>
```

Comment: here `onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display=''"` should be `onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='block'"`

Comment: At least remove the PHP code unless we can't execute this code

Comment: @Swati I have added 'block' I am still getting same error.

Comment: The error suggests that there is no element with Id 'register'.  So make sure that this modal code is loaded after taking your php code into consideration.  The code displayed above works.